# What's the equivalent of escaping strings for MySQL database input in Perl?

Tags: mysql, perl

What's the equivalent of escaping strings for MySql database input in perl?

Is Quote the best way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm) [placeholders](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values).

Here is an example (from [this link](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=7548)):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use DBI;

print "Enter the city you live in: ";
chomp( $city = <STDIN> );
print "Enter the state you live in: ";
chomp( $state = <STDIN> );

$dbh = DBI->connect(your db info here);
$sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT name WHERE city = ? AND state = ?" );
$sth->execute( $city, $state );
```

Comment: This is also what i was looking for!!